# c++ double shared_lock freezes the program on windows

Tags: c++, deadlock, readwritelock

When I am learning `shared_mutex` in C++17, I find a weired problem. If I call `shared_lock` twice in one thread, and call `unique_lock` in another thread, then my program will freeze. Like this:

```
std::mutex mutex;
std::shared_mutex s_mutex;

int i = 0;

void func() {
    auto lock = std::shared_lock(s_mutex);
    auto lock1 = std::shared_lock(s_mutex);
    ++i;
}

void func2() {
    auto lock = std::unique_lock(s_mutex);
    ++i;
}

int main() {
    auto t1 = std::thread([](){
        auto i = 10000;
        while(i--) {
            func();
        }
    });
    auto t2 = std::thread([](){
        auto i = 10000;
        while(i--) {
            func2();
        }
    });
    t2.join();
    t1.join();
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This problem seems only appear on windows, I tried it on Arch linux, it works well.

I'm using `g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0`.

I tried add `cout` after every lock like:

```
void func() {
    auto lock = std::shared_lock(s_mutex);
    std::cout << "t1 lock1\n";
    auto lock1 = std::shared_lock(s_mutex);
    std::cout << "t1 lock2\n";
    ++i;
}
```

Then I find it always freezes after `t1 lock1\n`, so I tried to step into lock1's constructor, and I find it freeze after this function:

```
static inline int
__gthread_active_p (void)
{
  return 1;
}
```

But I don't know why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to lock the mutex again in a thread that already holds a lock on the mutex has undefined behavior.

This applies to all mutex types except the `recursive*` ones.

Comment: Specifically "If lock_shared is called by a thread that already owns the mutex in any mode (exclusive or shared), the behavior is undefined." from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex/lock_shared

Comment: Typically, to prevent livelocks, as soon as thread tries to aquire exclusive lock, all new shared locks attempt are placed behind it in queue. If an attempt to aquire exclusive lock happens between two shared lock attempts in another thread, everything deadlocks: second thread waits for first thread to release first shared lock, while it stuck on attempt to aquire second shared lock, which will aquired only after second thread releases exclusive ownership.